# Ruby syntax confusion

Tags: ruby

I came across this method definition:

```
def stock_folder_map
  res = {}
  folders.each { |ff|
    ff.stocks.each { |s|
      res[s["id"]] = ff["name"]
    }
  }
end
```

Can anybody tell what `res = {}` and `res[s["id"]] = ff["name"]` mean?

Comment: It cannot be told only from the information you provide. We cannot tell what `folders` is.

Comment: If the function executes without error, you can at least infer from usage that `ff` must respond to `stocks` and `[]` or one or more of the nested collections must be empty.

Comment: @RichardCook Right. That is the best you can tell. Daiku's answer is about all you can tell from what is given. All other answers are guesses.

Comment: I think they're all equal in terms of guesswork!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res = {}` is assigning to the variable `res` a new, empty [Hash object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html).

`res[s["id"]] = ff["name"]` is assigning to whatever key `s["id"]` evaluates to, a value, retrieved from another hash, `ff`.

So if for example `[s["id"]]` evaluates to `:foo` and `ff["name"]` evaluates to `"bar"`, the above is equal to doing:

```
res[:foo] = "bar"
```

Now those `[]` are literals for accessing the hash by providing a key. In this case the keys are:

- `s["id"]` (which is another hash) for the `res` hash and
- `"name"` for the `ff` hash.

`s` is most propably another hash.

Comment: s is **most probably** another Hash. You cannot say it "for sure".

Comment: @quetzalcoatl right, updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are building up a new hash named `res`.  You are going through every `stock` in every `folder`, and creating a new element in `res` where the key is the id of the stock, and the value is the name of the folder.

Answer (score 2):

`res = {}` declares a local variable `res` and assigns an empty hash to it. Hashes are indexed using `[]` which, in Ruby terminology, means that hash instances *respond to* the `[]` message and yield some value corresponding to the key value passed to `[]`.

Meanwhile `folders.each` yields each element of the `folders` collection in turn to the loop body, assigning each element in turn to the loop variable `ff`. Given its usage, `ff` must respond both to `stocks` and `[]`. One possible way for `ff` to do this would be for it be an instance of a class such as `ClassOfFF` outlined below:

```
class ClassOfFF
  def stocks
    # Yield a collection (implementing Enumerable, for example)
  end

  def [](key)
    # Yield the element at "key"
  end
end
```

Each object from the collection returned by `stocks` must itself respond to `[]`. These objects might also be hashes or instances of another class that explicitly responds to `[]` like `ClassOfFF`, for example.

The statement `res[s["id"]] = ff["name"]` invokes `[]` on both `ff` and `ss` and assigns the value of `ff["name"]` to the element in `res` with key `s["id"]`.

Answer (score 1):

`res = {}` is an Hash object.`res[s["id"]]` is an Hash of Hash.`ff["name"]` is another Hash.`res[s["id"]] = ff["name"]` means you are putting the value of the Hash `ff` at key `"name"`,to the value (which is a key of `res`) of the Hash `s` at key `"id"`.

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudocode that might help.

```
def stock_folder_map
  res = {}                       # creates a new hash map named 'res'
  folders.each { |ff|            # for each folder in folders (ff = folder)
    ff.stocks.each { |s|         #   for each stock in ff.stocks (s = stock)
                                 #     we see that s is a hash map
      res[s["id"]] = ff["name"]  #     let id = s["id"] i.e. s.get("id") in java
                                 #     let name = ff["name"] i.e. ff.get("name") in java
                                 #     assign value in res i.e. res.put(id, name) in java
    }
  }
end
```

The documentation for [Hashes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html) might be useful.